# iPhone/iOS JSON parsing tutorial

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, uitableview

As a learning experience, I want to make an iPhone application that calls a webserver/webservice, retrieves a JSON response, and uses that response to populate the rows of a `UITableView` (assuming it converts the JSON into an `NSArray` first).

Anyone know of anything that might be useful?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

You will love this [framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/).

And you will love this [tool](http://ditchnet.org/httpclient/).

For learning about JSON you might like this [resource](http://json.org/).

And you'll probably love this [tutorial](http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c).

Comment: You're absolutely right about me loving that too @icnivad, thanks a lot for the lead this is very useful.

Comment: . Tutorial you mentioned requires DMG file but I could not find any DMG file on Link you mentioned for framework. that link  directs on github and contains a zip file with various classes and examples but I dont understand which part I need to insert in my project. Can you please help me?

Comment: Yeah, that project moved to github. Get it here: https://github.com/stig/json-framework/.

Comment: You'll also probably love hurl.it

Comment: That SBJson thing would be nice if it built.  Fails for me with 44 errors in Xcode 4 in OS X Lion.

Comment: I do love this answer. And I did love the way it was written. I will definitely love to vote it up now. ;)

Answer (score 57):

As of iOS 5.0 Apple provides the [NSJSONSerialization class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) "to convert JSON to Foundation objects and convert Foundation objects to JSON". No external frameworks to incorporate and according to [benchmarks](http://www.bonto.ch/blog/2011/12/08/json-libraries-for-ios-comparison-updated/) its performance is quite good, significantly better than SBJSON.

Comment: This words great as long as one is not planning to support iOS 4 and earlier versions.

Comment: Since It's now 2012 and iOS6 is imminent - that's more likely to be the case.

Comment: And the benchmark result is "404 Not Found".

Comment: Some updated benchmarks, showing NSJSONSerialization as the fastest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218583/jsonkit-benchmarks

Answer (score 6):

```
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];

NSString *url_str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Example APi Here"];

url_str = [url_str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURLRequest *request =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url_str]];

NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request  returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]

NSDictionary *statuses = [parser2 objectWithString:json_string error:nil];

 NSArray *news_array=[[statuses3 objectForKey:@"sold_list"] valueForKey:@"list"];

    for(NSDictionary *news in news_array)
{

    @try {
        [title_arr addObject:[news valueForKey:@"gtitle"]];    //values Add to title array

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {

        [title_arr addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

try out with this fastest JSON framework [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit). it's faster than normal JSON framework.

Comment: You're right, this is lightning fast!

Comment: The best JSON framework +1

Answer (score 4):

This is the tutorial I used to get to darrinm's answer. It's updated for ios5/6 and really easy. When I'm popular enough I'll delete this and add it as a comment to his answer.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/tutorial-fetch-and-parse-json-in-ios6/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to my tutorial, which walks you through :

- creating a JSON WCF Web Service from scratch  (and the problems you'll want to avoid)
- adapting it to read/write *SQL Server* data
- getting an iOS 6 app to use the JSON servies.
- using the JSON web services with JavaScript

http://mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/Services/WebServices-Page1.htm

All source code is provided, free of charge.  Enjoy.