# How to fetch data from this specific json (iphone)

Tags: iphone, json

Can anyone tell me how to find the `model` from this ?

it is giving me null all the time

```
 {
"Status": 200,
"Data": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "custno": "0000235",
        "locno": "00001",
        "mfg": "KABA-MAS",
        "model": "Cencon Gen II",
        "serial": "GF8912",
        "install": "2011-10-01",
        "removed": "0000-00-00",
        "warranty": "2012-01-10",
        "seragrno": "A",
        "equiploc": "Testing",
        "notes": "This is a test lock to test our system.  I this is it good.",
        "invoice": "A",
        "eqtype": "Lock",
        "plan": "1",
        "status": "0",
        "image": "cencon_main_1318703242.gif",
        "pmrequired": "1",
        "locktime": null,
        "lockby": null,
        "pmrequiredText": "Yes",
        "statusText": "Active",
        "planTypeText": "Plan I"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "custno": "0000235",
        "locno": "00001",
        "mfg": "adsdad",
        "model": "",
        "serial": "",
        "install": "2011-10-24",
        "removed": "0000-00-00",
        "warranty": "0000-00-00",
        "seragrno": "",
        "equiploc": "",
        "notes": "",
        "invoice": "",
        "eqtype": "",
        "plan": "",
        "status": "-1",
        "image": "",
        "pmrequired": "0",
        "locktime": null,
        "lockby": null,
        "pmrequiredText": "No",
        "statusText": "Pending",
        "planTypeText": null
    }
]
```

}

Comment: In what language? Using what library?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure...but there should be some obj.value type of structure, like in javascript
u can access it using something like "responce.data.model"

Answer (score 0):

assuming the JSON has been turned into an `NSDictionary`:

```
NSArray *items = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Data"];
for (item in items) {
    NSLog(@"model = %@", [item objectForKey:@"model"]);
}
```

If you are looking for how to turn the JSON into an `NSDictionary` try:

[iPhone/iOS JSON parsing tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813077/iphone-ios-json-parsing-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Use SBJsonParser for parsing the response.
And "data" field is array of dictionary.

```
SBJsonParser    *parser     = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

// parsing the JSON
NSMutableDictionary *jsonDictionary = [parser objectWithString:response];

NSMutableArray *dataArray = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
```

So, u can use something like this:-

```
for(NSMutableDictionary *tempDictionary in dataArray)          
{
    NSLog(@"id is %@",[dataArray objectForKey: @"description"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    NSData *responseData;
    NSMutableDictionary *response ;

    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com"];
    NSLog(@"%@",urlStr);
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];

    responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSString *json = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];

    response = (NSMutableDictionary *)[json JSONValue];
```

Then you'll have dictionary `response`. Now you can access it as

```
NSLog(@"%@",[response valueForKey:@"Data"] objectAtIndex:yourIndexValue] valueForKey:@"model"]);
```