# How to convert android method in objective c

Tags: android, iphone, cordova

I am new in iphone development. I created one code for android mobile using phonegap framework.But i don't have idea how to write same code for iphone mobile using objective c.
Please anyone have idea then guide me.How to create same code in objective c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following gist might help you to get the boilerplate stuff done to create an ios phonegap plugin. But as @binyamin mentioned you may still need to write the exact code yourself.

https://gist.github.com/1675595

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to translate the code for you, but there are several JSON frameworks for iOS that may help you, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813077/iphone-ios-json-parsing-tutorial).

Regarding `Encryption` and `Decryption` - we cannot help as we don't know those classes.