# parsing json giving error

Tags: iphone, json

I use facebook graph API, with the help of that, I get user friends list what I wanted. It is in JSON Format. As I do earlier I import json classes in my project I used the following method. But it throws an error which I don't understand what exactly I am missing here.

**My Code:**

```
-(void)getuserfriends
{
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"name,last_name,first_name",@"fields", nil];   
FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response =  [fbGraph doGraphGet:@"me/friends" withGetVars:dict];  
NSLog(@"getMeFriendsButtonPressed:  %@",fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);
//htmlresponse is string
NSMutableDictionary *newdict = [fb_graph_response.htmlResponse JSONValue];
}
```

Error:
Receive type NSString for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'JSONValue'

Comment: if problem is solved you must validate answer…

Answer (score 0):

It's because [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) does not have JSONValue method. You must use [JSON API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813077/iphone-ios-json-parsing-tutorial) who parse a string and return NSDictionary.

When you do this :

```
fb_graph_response.htmlResponse;
```

That return an NSString. And you call JSONValue who don't exist.