# Form in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I am making an iphone app which requires me to make use of website form to get values into database and which i can query through my iphone app in JSON form.

Now i am thinking that since my website form is having only 5-6 fields to fill up, can i make a form in my iphone app itself? I can then send that form data in JSON format to the webserver.
Someone please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the data to jason by post method.

```
-(void)registration:(NSString *)nickName 
  TeamName:(NSString *)teamName
  Age:(NSString *)age
  Nationality:(NSString *)countryName

{   
NSString *JSON = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"NICKNAME\":\"%@\"",nickName];
JSON = [JSON stringByAppendingFormat:@",\"TEAM_NAME\":\"%@\"",teamName];
JSON = [JSON stringByAppendingFormat:@",\"AGE\":\"%@\"",age];
JSON = [JSON stringByAppendingFormat:@",\"NATIONALITY\":\"%@\"",countryName];
NSLog(@"%@", JSON);

  NSData *postData = [JSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];    
  NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", kServerPath, kUserRegisterPath];

NSLog(@"Resgistration URL: %@", strURL);

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:120.0];    

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:[WebServices sharedInstance]];


if(theConnection) {
    NSLog(@"connection made");
}

else {
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error " message:@"Network not responding"  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

}
```

http://iosdevelopertips.com/networking/iphone-json-flickr-tutorial-part-1.html

[iPhone/iOS JSON parsing tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813077/iphone-ios-json-parsing-tutorial)

these links may help you