# How to convert the json string into array of elements?

Tags: ios, xcode, json, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

Here is my code to get a json response string

I am getting this string by using this method

```
NSDictionary *selector = [json valueForKey: @"Title"];
NSMutableArray *dictArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: selector,nil];
str1=[[dictArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"CompanyName"];
```

To print the "str1"

I am getting

```
(
    "hello@developer.com"
),
    (
    "hello@developer.com",
    "helloworld@microsoft.com"
),
    (
    "hello@developer.com"
),
    (
    "hello@developer.com"
),
    (
    "hello@developer.com"
),
    (
    "hello@developer.com"
),
    (
    "hello@developer.com"
),
    (
    "hello@developer.com"
)
```

)

I am trying to store in array by using "," operator

like this way

```
NSArray *SplitStringArray = [str1 componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
```

but I didn't split the string into array of elements

Could please any one help me?

Comment: BTW this is not how you parse json data. Look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5813223/986169

Comment: Indeed. I recommend JSONKit: https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    NSDictionary *selector = [json valueForKey: @"Title"];

    NSMutableArray *dictArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: selector,nil];

    NSMutableArray *str1Array=[[dictArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"CompanyName"];


        //note this line
    NSMutableArray *SplitStringArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (id eachArray in str1Array) {


        if ([eachArray count]>0) {


            for (int i = 0; i<[eachArray count]; i++) {

                NSString *emailid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[eachArray objectAtIndex:i]];

                [SplitStringArray addObject:emailid];


            }

        }

    }

    NSLog(@"SplitStringArray : %@",SplitStringArray);
```

Comment: update code and note that NSMutableArray *SplitStringArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Comment: previously i initialise the array]

Comment: thanks dude and have a great learning practices...for quick ref  join here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/682/iphone-ipad

Comment: hi friend i got the above solutions but i didn't get the solution for

Comment: hi friend i got the above solutions but i didn't get the solution for   {
Description = "Mic";EndDate = "/Date(1275832800000+0000)/";FriendlyName = TB3259;Id = 4;Location = "Building N-4105";Speakers =({Company = HP;Email = "janedoe@hp.com";
Name = "Jane Doe";Title = "Vice President";});StartDate = "/Date(1275829200000+0000)/";
                    },here is my json response in that i got selectors data but whenever i am trying get the friendly name i didn't get that one.In str1array takes the values whenever i append the table cell.The execution quit.what will i do please help me

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *SplitStringArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 
[SplitStringArray setArray:[str1 componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
```