# How to break parsed result?

Tags: iphone, ios

I m performing JSON parsing.
In return i m getting the result something like this:

```
{"login":"FALSE","userid":"Please enter correct Email Address"}
```

I want to retain the userid: message into some variable, so that i can perform functions on the basis of userid itself.

Suggestion please.

Thanks

Comment: some 'literature': http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON, this answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5813223/653513

Comment: If you're o.k. with supporting iOS >= 5.0 then you'll probably be best off using [NSJSONSerialization Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: my app will be dealing with iOS >= 5 only....i m quite confused about taking that userid: "message" into some string.not able to get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with a framework such as this,https://github.com/stig/json-framework

Example usage would be, assuming userId is declared in your header file.

```
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];

NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];

userId = [statuses valueForKey:@"userid"];
```

Now userId retains the value for the json value for userid from the json string

**UPDATE**: If you're only supporting **iOS >= 5.0** I would suggest the built in `NSJSONSerialization` class. If this is the case, your code will look more like this..

```
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableArray *jsonList = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

userId = [jsonList valueForKey:@"userid"];

NSLog(@"userid: %@", userId); // will print "Please enter correct Email Address"
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Do i need to include anything for adding the above lines?

Comment: Yes. The JSON Framework I mentioned above..

Comment: Updated my answer to include solution for iOS >= 5.0.

Comment: @skram: SBJSON is an excellent JSON framework - I use it in iOS 5 apps because I, personally, do not like the built-in framework.

Comment: My Server is down, so i m not able to test it for few more hours....i m gonna check upvote, bcoz, i guess this will work for me.

Comment: Great, if and or when you feel it is the `answer`. Check it off as such! Good Luck

Comment: Superb...that worked smoothly....Thanks Skram