# Beginner parsing JSON data?

Tags: json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone/iOS JSON parsing tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813077/iphone-ios-json-parsing-tutorial)

I have no clue how to parse JSON data from a website.

```
    {
"weather": {
  "curren_weather": [
    {
      "humidity": "54",
      "pressure": "1011",
      "temp": "50",
      "temp_unit": "f",
      "weather_code": "1",
      "weather_text": "Partly cloudy",
      "wind": [
        {
          "dir": "W",
          "speed": "9",
          "wind_unit": "kph"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

All that I want to do is store the "temp" and "weather_text" variables as NSStrings to be used in labels or whatever in my application...

The actual request url is something like: http://www.myweather2.com/developer/forecast.ashx?uac=(access-key)&output=json&query=(latitude,longitude)&temp_unit=f

Any thoughts on how to complete this?

Comment: Have you done any research? There are tons of JSON libraries for every language.

Comment: What language are you trying to parse the JSON with? Javascript / C# etc...

Comment: I always do research before posting on here, I tried following countlss tutorials but to no avail, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thats why I came here.

Comment: Objective C, iOS development

Comment: A quick Google search for "iOS JSON parsing" results in tons of hits. Didn't ***any*** of them suit your needs?

Answer (score 1):

I hope that's not the whole thing-- there should be a couple of extra `}`s at the end, or it isn't valid JSON.

Parse JSON using `NSJSONSerialization`'s `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` method. For the JSON above, it will give you an `NSDictionary`. You can then look up values using `NSDictionary` methods or key-value coding. If you fix the JSON and parse it this way, you'd use a key path like `weather.curren_weather.temp` (is it really `curren_weather` and not **`current_weather`**?) to get the temperature.