# How to retrieve PHP array in iOS

Tags: php, ios, arrays, json

I want to retrieve data from Array in iOS sent from PHP webservice. Following is the structure of the Array:

```
[
    {
        "fullname": "Kate Bell",
        "email": "kate-bell@mac.com"
    },
    {
        "fullname": "Kate Bell",
        "email": "www.creative-consulting-inc.com"
    },
    {
        "fullname": "Daniel Higgins",
        "email": "d-higgins@mac.com"
    },
    {
        "fullname": "John Appleseed",
        "email": "John-Appleseed@mac.com"
    }
]
```

Note: Array can be of any length.

PHP code:

```
mysql_select_db("mydb");

    $ReturningArray = array();

    foreach($Contacts_Array as $arr)
    {
        foreach($arr['emails'] as $email_address)
        {
            $query = "select email from table where email='".$email_address."'";
            $result = mysql_query($query);

            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

            if(empty($row))
            {
                $Contact = array(
                "fullname" => $arr['fullname'],
                 "email"   => $email_address
                 );

                $ReturningArray[] =  $Contact;
            }
        }

    }

    echo json_encode($ReturningArray);
```

Update:

I have tried this code but it doesn't work

```
    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
    {
        // NSString *Result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   // NSLog(@"Result in NonTroopeUsers : %@",Result);

        NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

        NSLog(@"COUNT :%d",[array count]);

        for (NSDictionary* item in array)
        {
            NSString *fullname = [item objectForKey:@"fullname"];
            NSString *email = [item objectForKey:@"email"];

            NSLog(@"Full name: %@",fullname);

            NSLog(@"email: %@",email);
        }

    }
```

Array count is Zero but the commented code shows data recieved in nslog.

Comment: There are lots of similar questions, [one of them](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5813077/767730). There is no difference if JSON is send from PHP, RoR or .NET.

Comment: Did you try to set `NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves` in options? You can set NSError and catch the error the parser returns to you in `error:&error`

Comment: Yeah I did that. Doesn't work.

Comment: I guess that what you receive is not what you expect : do an NSLog of your response

Comment: Yeah I did that. First two commented lines show correct response in nslog.

Answer (score 0):

Do not perform  the conversion in `connection: didReceiveData:` method. We might have only a partial data. And this may get called many times to giving chunks of datas. You have to add these chunks of partial datas to get the full Data.

You can use NSJSONSerialization for parsing the JSON.

```
NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Also,

Create an memberVariable

```
 NSMutableData *netData;
```

Implement the following methods

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
     if(netData == nil)
          netData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    [netData appendData:data];
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
      //// Here convert the Full Data to JSON, 
     NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:netData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
     NSLog(@"%@",array);


}
```

Comment: The JSON is an array, not dictionary. Please edit your answer.

Comment: I am getting array count 0.

Comment: Use NSUTF8StringEncoding when you convert String to Data. Hope it helps

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",array); prints (null)

Comment: can you give me the url to which you are hitting request

Comment: NSString *Result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Result in NonTroopeUsers : %@",Result);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31639/discussion-between-ironman-and-champtaurus)

Answer (score 0):

well

```
id responseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
if(!error){
  if([responseArray isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
     for(id entry in responseArray){
        if([entry isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
         // do what you want with the dictionary
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. I was using var_dump($SomeVariable) at the start of php file. When I removed that I am able to retrieve data.