# Json Parsing a Nested Table View iOS

Tags: ios, json, parsing, nsdictionary

I am trying to make a Master Detail structured app that's data in both the Master Controller and Detail Controller is pulled from a website. On the website, there are a list of companies and if you click on a certain company, more info about that particular company will show. I want to have my app like this. In the Master Controller, I want the list of companies pulled from the website and if you tap the company then it will navigate to another controller with more information about that company.

I am clueless as to how to do this. However, I am able to present a table view that shows info about one company but that is all I can do. So please ask questions if you do not understand. This is kind of hard to explain.

Comment: it really depends on what data u have? any example data you have?

Comment: There are numerous dupes of this question on SO and tutorials on the 'Net. You should be able to find one using Google. Also, the question is not related to Xcode.

Comment: First of all H2CO3, no I cannot find anything on the entire internet after days of searching. Secondly, the question is related to Xcode because that's where the table view comes into play. Thanks for giving me a -1 and deleting the xcode tag.. but anyways, I'm very frustrated with this, and I am just looking for someone to point me in some direction. I just want to put text from a website into a table view in XCODE and if you tap on that text it will push to another controller which will reveal more info about that text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you search the internet for day and couldn't find anything, you have to tell us what your search for, or where/how you searched because it takes 30 seconds to find:

- [iPhone/iOS JSON parsing tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813077/iphone-ios-json-parsing-tutorial)
- http://www.raywenderlich.com/13097/intro-to-restkit-tutorial
- http://liebke.github.io/restkit-github-client-example/

So it's hard to believe that you "cannot find anything on the entire internet after days of searching". If it's really the case, that means you are a beginner (and that's not wrong at all, we were all beginners at least once) but in this case, you should not try to teach H2CO3 ;)

And your question is not related to xcode.