# SBJson Parse Data on iOS

Tags: ios, json, parsing

I want to parse those Json that has a structure like this on iOS, with SBJSon libs
Can anyone help me? thanks so much!

**{"error":{"username":["The username has already been taken."],"email":["The email has already been taken."]}}**

Comment: Your question not clear dude . Is that bolded words are the response you are getting or what?

Comment: You can use SBJson Library for parsing JSON structures in iOS.. Heres the link http://stackoverflow.com/a/5813223/1042240

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *str=@"{\"error\":{\"username\":[\"The username has already been taken.\"],\"email\":[\"The email has already been taken.\"]}}";

NSData *data=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: nil];

NSLog(@"dic is %@",json);
```

//output

```
dic is {
    error =     {
        email =         (
            "The email has already been taken."
        );
        username =         (
            "The username has already been taken."
        );
    };
}
```

**Using SBJSon**

```
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
NSDictionary *results = [str JSONValue];
```

Comment: He's asking that parse the JSON through SBJson!

Comment: If json can be parse using inbuilt function of objective-C then who needs extra file to be included,If really wants to increase project size then use SBJson I wrote this also.

Answer (score 0):

```
SBJsonParser * parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSObject * responseobj = [parser objectWithData:data]; // for NSData
NSObject * responseobj = [parser objectWithString:string]; // for NSString
```

In your case "responseobj" will be of type `NSDictionary`.