# Show Facebook Wall of Page in iOS

Tags: ios, json, facebook, facebook-wall

i am currently working on an App and i want to show the Posts of a Facebook Page in a TableView in iOS. What I read before was I can get the Data from https://graph.facebook.com/106407802732665/feed?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN .

I know I have to parse the JSON and put it into the TableView.

But I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you first parse JSON and get data for facebook feed,it have more data with keys,you use required keys and customize your table view cells. refer this example code

[parse json ios programming tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/fetch-parse-json-ios-programming-tutorial/)

[iphone ios json parsing tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813077/iphone-ios-json-parsing-tutorial)

Comment: could you please describe a bit better wgat to do??