# Parse JSON array of objects in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, ios6

I have a JSON array of objects with the following layout:

```
[{
    "user_privacy": "Private",
    "latitude": "53.34885596487662",
    "longitude": "-6.255970895290375",
    "address": "",
    "quick_ezpoint": false,
    "tags": "test",
    "owner": true,
    "value": "TQJ539"
},{
    "user_privacy": "Private",
    "latitude": "53.34885596487662",
    "longitude": "-6.255970895290375",
    "address": "",
    "quick_ezpoint": false,
    "tags": "test",
    "owner": true,
    "value": "TQJ539"
}]
```

I tried this code but its not working:

```
NSArray *ezpoints = [JSON valueListAttributes];
                for (NSArray *ezpoint in ezpoints) {
                    NSLog(@"%@",[ezpoint description]);
                }
```

Comment: There are at least several of these questions every day. Come on, people, do some basic debugging/google/Stackoverflow searching before asking!

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone/iOS JSON parsing tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813077/iphone-ios-json-parsing-tutorial)

Comment: @user1774937:I can't you. You dont know how to get JSON from url? or You to parse your JSON value? please tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(NSDictionary * dict in ezpoints)
{
    [userPrivacyArray addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"user_privacy"]];
    [LattitudeArray addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"latitude"]];
    [LongitudeArray addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"longitude"]]
}
```

parse the data using `valueForKey` using key you can identify your json data and stored into NSArray, NSString where you want.

here `userPrivacyArray,LattitudeArray,LongitudeArray` all are array.

try this stuff.

Comment: It says, "Use of undeclared identifier dict"

Comment: @Pawan I didn't get your question.

Comment: Its done bro, i got the answer from some-other "SO" thread. When i was using this code, the compiler was giving me this error "Use of undeclared identifier dict.". Anyways, it is done. np. TC. :-)