# How multiple json parsing in ios?

Tags: ios, json, parsing

i have a problem. I have to parse this json:

```
{
        "category_id" = 1;
        fullname = "Wiadomo\U015bci";
        name = wiadomosci;
        "page_index" = 0;
        "show_live" = 1;
    },
        {
        "category_id" = 2;
        fullname = Kultura;
        name = kultura;
        "page_index" = 1;
        "show_live" = 0;
    },
        {
        "category_id" = 3;
        fullname = Rozrywka;
        name = rozrywka;
        "page_index" = 2;
        "show_live" = 0;
    },
        {
        "category_id" = 4;
        fullname = Biznes;
        name = biznes;
        "page_index" = 3;
        "show_live" = 0;
    }
```

I have two arrays with category_id, full name, name and page_index.
How to do?

I used AFnetworking:

```
self.manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [self.manager setRequestSerializer:[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]];
    self.manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [self.manager GET:@"http://webapi.test.pl/newsCategoriesForMobileApp/iphone" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

and I'don't know how to parsing json.

Comment: can u give ur url name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have array of dictionaries, you need to just do the following

```
for(NSDictionary *dic in jsonArray){

    NSLog(@"%@, %@, %@",[dic objectForKey:@"category_id"],[dic objectForKey:@"fullname"],[dic objectForKey:@"page_index"]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if this array named array. You can get property by

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [array objectAtIndex:page_index];
NSString *fullname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"fullname"]];
NSInteger category_id = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"category_id"] integerValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813077/iphone-ios-json-parsing-tutorial)

In short:
Use [NSJSONSerialization class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
and check [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)