# Parsing JSON in iOS application

Tags: ios, xcode, gson

As I'm a newbie in iOS development, please help me to parse the JSON output.

My JSON output:

```
{"sbi":[{"Emp_Id":1001,"Emp_Name":"James","Designation":"Manager","Skills":["C,C++"]},{"Emp_Id":1002,"Emp_Name":"John","Designation":"Asst.Manager","Skills":["Java,PHP"]},{"Emp_Id":1003,"Emp_Name":"Joe","Designation":"Chief Manager","Skills":["Oracle,HTML"]}]}
```

When we launch an app, I should get `sbi`  on the first view and if I select that particular row, I should get all the details related to `sbi` on the next view, i.e. `EmpId`, `EmpName`, `Designation`, `Skills`, ...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the API docs and several hundred other questions. Basically: `+ (id)JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)data options:(NSJSONReadingOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error`

Comment: Add your code of you are getting responce .

Comment: How is this related to `gson`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone/iOS JSON parsing tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813077/iphone-ios-json-parsing-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

Parse the json to a dictionary object with

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:yourJson options:0 error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following link to Json parsing Demo.It will help you to learn Json parsing.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Comment: Overkill for the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    -(void)Startconnection:(NSString *)urlString
{
   NSLog(@"%@",urlString); 
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:"your url string "]];
 connetion1=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self] ;
    webData = [NSMutableData data];

}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [webData setLength: 0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [webData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 //   [ShowAlert showMyAlert:@"Network Alert" :@"No Internet connection detected"];

}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

    NSError *myError = nil;
    responceDic=nil;
 responceDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];

    NSLog(@"%@",responceDic  );
}
```

In the .h file declare NSXMLParserDelegate delegate

```
@interface webservice : NSObject<NSXMLParserDelegate>
{

    NSMutableData *  webData;
    NSString *currentData;
    NSURLConnection * connetion1;

}
```

Comment: Get the responce   NSLog(@"%@",[[responceDic objectforkey:@"sbi"] objectforkey:@"Emp_Id"]);